# JS: pass variable onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-templates

I'm trying to pass a variable to a function, I know there are many topics about this, and I've nearly tried all suggestions, but still can't get it to work, these are my attempts:

**edit:** without the onclick, everything is working fine

```
var filename = file.name;

<button class="btn btn-danger delete" onclick="deleteImage(\''+filename+'\');">
```

**results in:** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" onclick="deleteImage(&quot;'+type+'&quot;);">
```

**results in (alert):** 'filename'

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" onclick="deleteImage('" + filename + "');">
```

**results in:** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" onclick="deleteImage(" + filename + ");">
```

**result in:** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

this is the full code (modified, blueimp fileuploader)

```
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { 
            // add the image urls to the file inputbox
            var filename = file.name;
            var prev = $("#mFile").val(); 
            $("#mFile").val(prev + file.name + ","); 

            %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="modules/mod_stern_form_prijsopgave/upload/server/php/files/{%=file.name%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="modules/mod_stern_form_prijsopgave/upload/server/php/files/thumbnail/{%=file.name%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="modules/mod_stern_form_prijsopgave/upload/server/php/files/{%=file.name%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" onclick="deleteImage('" + filename + "');" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Verwijderen</span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

**and testing like this:**

```
    function deleteImage(filename) {
      alert(filename);
    }
```

what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your advice

Comment: What system is this? Looks like it might be jQuery templates or knockoutjs? This question needs better tagging.

Comment: yeah, jquery, I'll add the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the template format for onclick value:

```
onclick="deleteImage('{%=filename%}');"
```

try file.name as well

```
onclick="deleteImage('{%=file.name%}');"
```

Comment: lol..I've tried something close to this.. this worked! thank you so much. this might bring a grin upon your face: I just spent 2 hours on this

Answer (score 3):

```
<button id="deleteOnClick" class="btn btn-danger delete">...</button>
```

and in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("deleteOnClick").onclick = function(){deleteImage(filename);}
```

**edit:**

if you want to delete the file specified only by the original filename value:

```
var deleteByFile = (function (filename){
    return function(){deleteImage(filename);};
}(filename));
document.getElementById("deleteOnClick").onclick = deleteByFile
```

Comment: all suggestions resulted in: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: did you add the `id` to the button? if not then you can use `$(".btn-danger").click(deleteByFile);` instead.

Comment: fixed it now using gp.'s answer, thanks a lot for your help mate

Comment: Thank you a lot, "double wrapping" method saved me

Answer (score 2):

You can't access JS variables from your HTML. You must do something like this:

```
var filename = 'testing';
document.getElementById('testdiv')
    .setAttribute('onclick', "alert('" + filename + "')");
filename = 'more testing';
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZmbn/).

Comment: I've tried this one aswell, results in: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @MaartenHartman Well then it's a problem somewhere else in the code, because my code most definitely does NOT have a `}`.

Comment: I know, and normally your suggestion should work, but without the onclick everything is working fine, so the code isn't flawed.

Comment: thanks for your help so far, last suggestion resulted in: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: @Maarten Well, is your div's `id` "testdiv"?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help doorknob, fixed it now using gp.'s answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `onclick="deleteImage(" + filename + ");"`

Answer (score -1):

You can set a varaiable like var counter = 1;

Wherever it is required, you can update it like

```
     onclick="updateCount('+counter+')"
```